# Integrate AdminLTE to django project

Tags: python, django, integration, adminlte

I want to integrate AdmineLTE to my django project, with the help of its
README file.
https://github.com/StephenPCG/django-adminlte-templates

I followed all steps required in the file, but when I'm running my app, and want to login, I'm getting the following error.

```
You're using the staticfiles app without having set the required STATIC_URL setting.
```

which come from here

```
django-adminlte-templates/AdminLTE/templatetags/AdminLTE.py in <module>
bootstrap_url_base = _bootstrap_url_base if _bootstrap_url_base else static('bootstrap')
```

Comment: Starting with the obvious... have you defined `STATIC_URL` in your settings file?

Comment: @solarissmoke in AdminLTE projects settings.py STATIC was defined
 'STATIC': {
        # settings related to static resources
        # to use maxcdn, change None to: //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/, default use local dist
        'BOOTSTRAP_URL_BASE': None,
    },

Comment: You still need a `STATIC_URL` to be defined in your core Django settings. This is completely separate from the AdminLTE settings.

Comment: I added STATIC_URL, and now working. Thanks @solarissmoke